# Circular Buffer

Tags: performance, c, circular-list

For my current project I need a circular buffer, which is able to do the following things:

- Push something to it (to the head).
- Pop something from it (from the tail). I *don't* need the popped data.
- Peak the head and tail (no popping).
- Iterate through the currently contained elements.

Here is my C implementation.

**circularBuffer.h:**

```
#ifndef CIRCULAR_BUFFER_H
#define CIRCULAR_BUFFER_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct circularBuffer {
  void *data;         // Holds the buffer data.
  size_t headOffset;  // The next position the buffer will write to.
  size_t tailOffset;  // The position of the buffer tail.
  size_t elementSize; // Size of one element contained in the buffer.
  size_t numElements; // Number of elements the buffer is able to hold at once.
  bool   isEmpty;     // Flag, which holds, whether the buffer is empty. 
                      // Allows to fill the whole buffer without losing the ability 
                      // to determine, whether its empty or not.
};

struct circularBuffer *circularBuffer_create(size_t numElements, size_t elementSize);

// Push/Pop
void  circularBuffer_push(struct circularBuffer *buf, void *ptr);
int   circularBuffer_popTail(struct circularBuffer *buf);

// Get data
size_t circularBuffer_containedCount(struct circularBuffer *buf);
void *circularBuffer_peakTail(struct circularBuffer *buf);
void *circularBuffer_peakHead(struct circularBuffer *buf);

#endif /* !defined CIRCULAR_BUFFER_H */
```

**circularBuffer.c:**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "circularBuffer.h"

struct circularBuffer *circularBuffer_create(size_t numElements, size_t elementSize) {
  struct circularBuffer *tmp = calloc(1, sizeof(struct circularBuffer));

  if (!tmp) { return NULL; }

  tmp->data = malloc(numElements * elementSize);

  if (!tmp->data) {
    free(tmp);
    return NULL;
  }

  tmp->numElements = numElements;
  tmp->elementSize = elementSize;
  tmp->isEmpty = true;

  return tmp;
}

void circularBuffer_push(struct circularBuffer *buf, void *ptr) {
  if (!buf->isEmpty && buf->headOffset == buf->tailOffset) {
    buf->tailOffset = (buf->tailOffset + 1) % buf->numElements;
  }

  memcpy(buf->data + buf->headOffset*buf->elementSize, ptr, buf->elementSize);
  buf->headOffset = (buf->headOffset + 1) % buf->numElements;
  buf->isEmpty = false;
}

void *circularBuffer_peakTail(struct circularBuffer *buf) {
  return buf->isEmpty ? NULL : buf->data + buf->tailOffset * buf->elementSize;
}

void *circularBuffer_peakHead(struct circularBuffer *buf) {
  if (buf->isEmpty)                          { return NULL; }
  else if (buf->data + buf->headOffset != 0) { return buf->data + (buf->headOffset-1) * buf->elementSize; } 
  else                                       { return buf->data + (buf->numElement-1) * buf->elementSize; }
}

int circularBuffer_popTail(struct circularBuffer *buf) {
  if (buf->isEmpty) { return 0; }       // Empty buffer.

  buf->tailOffset = (buf->tailOffset + 1) % buf->numElements; 
  if (buf->tailOffset == buf->headOffset) { 
    buf->isEmpty = true; 
  }

  return 1;
}

size_t circularBuffer_containedCount(struct circularBuffer *buf) {
  if (buf->isEmpty) { return 0; }
  else if (buf->tailOffset < buf->headOffset) { return buf->headOffset - buf->tailOffset; }
  else if (buf->tailOffset == buf->headOffset) { return buf->numElements; }
  else return buf->numElements - buf->tailOffset + buf->headOffset;
}
```

**Notes:** I explicitly didn't check whether the buffer pointer is `NULL` in every function. The user should take care of it.

This basic implementation allows me to do everything I listed above quite nicely I think. Is there anything I could do better according performance? I'll probably use this pretty heavily.

Comment: "better according performance?"  -->  Is that only execution performance (faster better) or are you considering memory usage performance (lower better) or maintenance (simple better) or portability (more standard better)?

Comment: Why isn't `circularBuffer_peakHead()` just `return buf->isEmpty ? NULL : buf->data + buf->headOffset * buf->elementSize;`?

Comment: Minor point, the word you want is 'peek' not 'peak'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Overall fairly good.  Good use of `size_t`, naming conventions and portability.
2. 6.1 vs half-dozen the other idea. Consider `size_t UsageCount` vs. `bool isEmpty`.  This value is a direct report of count of elements eliminating `size_t circularBuffer_containedCount()` as a function.  IMO, it will make other parts of code simpler too.

   ```
   #define circularBuffer_containedCount(buf)  (buf->UsageCount)
   #define circularBuffer_isEmpty(buf)         (buf->UsageCount == 0)
   #define circularBuffer_isFull(buf)          (buf->UsageCount >= buf->numElements)
   ```
3. Making implementation private.  (Especially if you do no go for idea #2.)  Only define `struct circularBuffer` in the `.c` file.  In the `.h`, just declare the pointer `struct circularBuffer *`.
4. Missing function:  To complement `circularBuffer_create()`, I'd expect `circularBuffer_destroy()`
5. Functions that do not alter `buf` should have `const` in their signature to help show that and to enforce it.

   ```
   // circularBuffer_peakHead(struct circularBuffer *buf)
   circularBuffer_peakHead(const struct circularBuffer *buf)
   ```
6. Agree with [@vnp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/123157/29485) about code problem.  Alternative solution: add cast.  I like the visible portion of code (header file) using `void *data`.

   ```
   //buf->data + buf->headOffset != 0
   (char *) buf->data + buf->headOffset != 0
   ```
7. Minor: `circularBuffer_create()` omits the explicit initialization of some fields counting on `calloc()` to do the zero fill.  I'd rather see the explicit initialization.
8. Minor: for debugging purposes, suggest `calloc(numElements, elementSize);` rather than `malloc()` as it s nice to have all the allocated memory in a known state.  It also has a benefit on the rare machine where `numElements * elementSize` overflows, yet `calloc()` would work.
9. Thought: `circularBuffer_create()` does 2 allocations.  It could do only 1 and then segment the parts.  I'm on the fence as to the value of speed vs. clarity here.
10. Minor: Style: Recommend a bit more distinctiveness between functions that just a single empty line.
11. Symmetry in naming: use 1 pair or the other - suggest shorter pair

    ```
    circularBuffer_pushHead();
    circularBuffer_popTail();
    // or
    circularBuffer_push();
    circularBuffer_pop();
    // not 
    circularBuffer_push();
    circularBuffer_popTail();
    ```
12. `circularBuffer_push()` should not add data if buffer is full.  Better to either return error code, fault, set `errno`, but do not overwrite data.
13. Use `0` or `NULL`, not both for the null pointer.  I am suspicious about the functionality of `circularBuffer_peakHead()`  `if (buf->data + buf->headOffset != 0)` looks odd.
14. `if (!tmp->data)` is only a problem if `numElements * elementSize` is non-zero.  Strange to have `elementSize` of zero, but no real reason to disallow it.  On the other hand, if code passed in `numElements == 0`, that is more difficult to handle with other code like `% buf->numElements`.

Comment: Wow, so many great ideas. I wasn't thinking that so much could be made clearer/better. Thank you! The only thing I won't change is point 12. I explicitly need the behavior to override the old data, if new data arrives. Maybe I'll add a boolean return value to report, whether something was overwritten though. Thanks again :)

Comment: And how would I handle 9.? I was thinking about an array in the structure, but since I don't know the size, this won't work. How is this normally done?

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive For #9, `struct circularBuffer *tmp = calloc(1, sizeof *tmp + numElements * elementSize); tmp->data = &tmp[1];`

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive A different  way to do this since C99 is with [_flexible array member_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) which is an indefinite sized array at the end of a structure.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting - never heard of it before, but I'm *relatively* new to C, so I guess that's fine...

Comment: @@LastSecondsToLive OTOH, `struct circularBuffer *tmp = calloc(1, sizeof *tmp + numElements * elementSize); tmp->data = &tmp[1];` may not provide the alignment needed `tmp->data` when it is returned in `circularBuffer_popTail()`.  In fact, the whole `tmp->data = malloc(numElements * elementSize);` idea is prone to alignment issues and may be a _major_ fault with this curricular queue idea.  The issue is that not only is each element needing `elementSize`, it may need a certain alignment, something not insured by your code. Hmmm, will ponder that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37230/discussion-between-chux-and-lastsecondstolive).

Answer (score 4):

- **void * data;**

  results in the

  ```
  warning: arithmetic on a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-Wpointer-arith]
    memcpy(buf->data + buf->headOffset*buf->elementSize, ptr, buf->elementSize);
  ```

  For portability make it `char * data;`.
- **Fail early**

  If a condition

  ```
  buf->data + buf->headOffset != 0
  ```

  ever fails, the structure is badly corrupted. You should fail immediately, with as much noise as possible (the core dump suffices). In no case you can mask the problem.

Comment: Do you mean the line in `peak_Head`? I think this is actually wrong and just `buf->headOffset` was meant. Do you want me to delete this post, overthink and ask again, because of broken code?

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive It is totally up to you. For me, the code fits the CodeReview format perfectly well. You are also welcome to post the fixed version as a follow-up question.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep it up, wait a couple more hours, rewrite a better version and may do a follow up :)

Answer (score 2):

Modulo arithmetic might be expensive.  Consider replacing:

```
buf->tailOffset = (buf->tailOffset + 1) % buf->numElements;
```

with something more along the form of:

```
if (++buf->tailOffset == buf->numElements) buf->tailOffset = 0;
```